# Deleting nodes in BST using free(N)

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, free

I'm coding a binary search tree and I'm having a little trouble finding a way to delete node effectively.

I have this code :

```
struct node* deleteNode(int i, struct node *N)

{
    if (N==NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (i<N->value)
    {
        N->size--;
        N->lChild=deleteNode(i,N->lChild);
    }
    else if (i>N->value)
    {
        N->size--;
        N->rChild=deleteNode(i,N->rChild);
    }
    else if (N->lChild==NULL)
    {
        return N->rChild;
    }
    else if (N->rChild==NULL)
    {
        return N->lChild;
    }
    else
    {
        N->size--;
        N->value=findMin(N->rChild);
        N->rChild=deleteNode(N->value,N->rChild);
    }
    return N;
}
```

And N is a node structure which have 5 fields : value, lChild, rChild, size, height.
In fact what I'm doing here is to make the tree not to point toward the node that I want to delete but when I'm trying to put something like :

```
    else if (N->rChild==NULL)
    {
        free(N);
        N=NULL;
        return N->lChild;
    }
```

Or every similar looking code, it doesn't work. Can someone point me in the right direction please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're saying N=NULL and then calling N->lchild N is null and pointing to nothing so how do you expect to get the lchild value?

Since this is homework I won't give a direct answer but hints.

To delete the node, check if it has children, if it doesnt free it and remove references to it such as the parents child ptr.
If it has 1 child swap the ptr that points to the node you want to delete with the child and free the node. The same applies if you also have 2 children.

Comment: add a comment for such things

Comment: Yeah that was a bad example, but well even if I don't put N=NULL; when launched, the program crashs. (so with only free(N); so apparently he doesn't like me using N->something after freeing that N), the problem is that I really don't know where to put that.

Comment: you want to swap the pointers first and THEN free the node and remember to remove all references to that node to avoid a double free

Comment: Would putting it after the "return" is the solution (in fact there is no way I can check if the thing is really freed correctly, that's kinda annoying) or should I keep a reference of the parent node and free the child node from there? (I hope it's the first of the twos, keeping that reference seems... complicated).

Comment: Why do you need to return the node if you're going to delete it? If you do need to return it you need to free it after the return in whatever method called delete node

Comment: In fact when I'm deleting a Node that is not a leaf I make a link between the parent and the child(s) of the node I want to delete.
Would that work?
    else if (N->rChild==NULL)
    {
        return N->lChild;
        free(N);
        N=NULL;
    }
Or should I use a temporary variable to keep N->lChild so I can return it and free(N) ?

Comment: That would work but you would have to return the value of lChild and not a reference since you will be freeing N